# Howto use the DrawerLayout with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have the `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` with DrawerLayout   working ok but now I wanted to port it to `ConstraintLayout`. This is not going so well and wanted to ask for advice?

ORIGINAL WORKING XML:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.port.android.ui.ActivityMain">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="exitAddress"
                android:text="Exit Address" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

PORTING TO ConstraintLayout: (not working the drawer is stale, cannot swipe in/out)

The `"@+id/frame"` is where i insert Frags

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.port.android.ui.ActivityMain">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22000003"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="exitAddress"
                android:text="Exit Address" />

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: remove constraint layout from the parent, only include it in the content portion of the drawer

Comment: Thanks, Can you be more specif..

Comment: The drawer (your `NavigationView`, in this case) still needs to be the last direct child of the `DrawerLayout`. That is, move it to after the closing `CoordinatorLayout` tag.

Comment: Thanks That worked. Now I have [another cool problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116622/i-try-to-get-this-drawerlayout-working-but-cannot-find-what-is-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">    
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your button and frame layout widgets in a constraint layout instead of a linear layout. But, you should use linear layout for defining NavHostFragment and you can seperately define NavigationView as the last child of DrawerLayout. Note: Here LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout are 2 childs of drawer layout. Linear layout holds your NavHostFragment, ConstraintLayout holds your Toolbar, widgets that you define in FrameLayout, and Exit button. Drawer Layout will be the 3rd child.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, late to the party, but I don't understand how top answer works since Android Studio is preventing to do that.

Because of that I investigated further and found this to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

        <!--your ConstraintLayout code here, like this button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butt"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="30"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/butt"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextIzvornaValuta" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```