# I try to get this DrawerLayout working but cannot find what is wrong

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Everything works I can pull out drawer and toolbar is ok but the `"@+id/frame"` where I add my Fragment is not visible.

XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.port.android.ui.ActivityMain">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11463845"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="exitAddress"
            android:text="Exit Address" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Here in the Android Studio Layout inspector I clearly see that a Fragment with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` is added into the `"@+id/frame"` but as you see nothing shows.
.

[image]

Here is the Fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_chat_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/upload"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_create_new_folder_black_24dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message_body"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:hint="@string/message_hint"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/post_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/message_post"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how I add Fragment:

```
                mFragManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame, (Fragment) Class.forName(tag).newInstance(), tag)
                    .addToBackStack(tag)
                    .commit();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey @Tord did you ever get an answer to this?